# how do i copy formula and paste it?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy formula within cells, so i use 'xlfillcopy' but I get series value.
my code is like;

`Set Cell(1) = Range("A1:A1")`

`Set Cell(2) = Range("A1:A5")`

`Cell(1).AutoFill Destination:=Cell(2), Type:=xlFillCopy`

and in Cell A1=N12, so what i want to do is write formula "=N12" to all in the A1:A5.
But vba writes A1=N12,  A2=M12, ... and so on.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `Range("A1:A5").Formula = "=N$12"` ?

Comment: OMG why couldn't i come up with this! thanks